# How do I listen another user's audio and video status in webrtc flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-web

Is there any way that can I detect another user disabled video or mute audio? I want to show message that "user b muted audio" and "user b turned off video".

I used: flutter_webrtc: ^0.8.0

Comment: Can you use firebase / any real-time DB to detect is muted or not?

Comment: No, I don't want to use that?